Customize Ema widget tradingview
Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong? I have to change the color of the EMA5 to Red and EMA10 ro Yellow, but it doesn't work.
new TradingView.widget({
"container_id": "tradingview_widget",
"width": "100%",
"height": "400px",
"symbol": "BINANCE:BTCUSDT",
"interval": "D",
"timezone": "Etc/UTC",
"theme": "light",
"style": "1",
"locale": "en",
"toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
        "enable_publishing": false
, "studies_overrides": {
    "moving average exponential.0.plot.color": "#FF0000",
    "moving average exponential.1.plot.color": "#FFFF00"
        },
        "studies": [
            {
                id: "MAExp@tv-basicstudies",
                inputs: {
                    length: 5
                }
            
            },
            {
            id: "MAExp@tv-basicstudies",
            inputs: {
                length: 10
            }
            }
        ]});

